# Adding options to Drupal search

Tags: forms, search

I've been working on a site and I need to change the search.

I've changed the search form with hook_form_alter(), added some checkboxes, ... Now I need to get the new data to the hook_search_execute() function?

How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. I alway wanted to use Search API, but wasn't sure how to do it.

I figured it out with:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575289/extending-drupal-7-search

Answer (score 1):

Drupal's search platform is rudimentary one. You can't really extend it, best you can do is to replace it. Most popular free platform now seems to be [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), connected to Drupal with [Apache Solr Search Integration](https://drupal.org/project/ApacheSolr).

If Solr's to much, [Search API](https://drupal.org/project/search_api) integrates with views pretty neat, you can have one field for search and other as Views filters.